# How can I pass LINQ .Where condition as parameter?

Tags: c#, linq, parameter-passing, where-clause

In LINQ, is it possible to pass `.Where` conditions as parameter?

```
IList<Object> obj = persons
    .Where(p => p.Text.Contains("x") || p.Text.Contains("y"))
    .ToList();
```

So that more than one dynamic conditions

Comment: you can define `Func<IList<Object>, bool>  objectWhere` then pass it `persons.Where(objectWhere);`

Answer (score 0):

The single line you have posted is equivalent to the following:

```
bool filter( Person p )
{
    return p.Text.Contains( "x" ) || p.Text.Contains( "y" );
}

IList<Object> obj = persons.Where( filter ).ToList();
```

I hope this answers your question.